# `ionic serve` doesn't reload/rebuild when changing files under app's sub folders

Tags: build, ionic2, livereload

I'm trying to follow angular's **folder-by-feature structure** in my ionic3 project. So I create a *feature* folder under `app` folder, like this:

```
- src/
    - app/
        - about/
            - about.module.ts
            - components／
                - about.component.html
                - about.component.ts
                - about.component.scss
```

When changing any file under `about` folder, `ionic serve` fire a rebuild process,  but built files change nothing:

```
> ionic-app-scripts serve

[10:50:52]  ionic-app-scripts 2.1.3 
[10:50:52]  watch started ... 
[10:50:52]  build dev started ... 
[10:50:52]  clean started ... 
[10:50:52]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[10:50:52]  copy started ... 
[10:50:52]  transpile started ... 
[10:50:57]  transpile finished in 4.74 s 
[10:50:57]  preprocess started ... 
[10:50:57]  deeplinks started ... 
[10:50:57]  deeplinks finished in 181 ms 
[10:50:57]  preprocess finished in 183 ms 
[10:50:57]  webpack started ... 
[10:50:57]  copy finished in 5.14 s 
[10:51:08]  webpack finished in 10.82 s 
[10:51:08]  sass started ... 
[10:51:10]  sass finished in 2.06 s 
[10:51:10]  postprocess started ... 
[10:51:10]  postprocess finished in 5 ms 
[10:51:10]  lint started ... 
[10:51:10]  build dev finished in 17.86 s 
[10:51:10]  watch ready in 17.95 s 
[10:51:10]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/ 

// -----> change any files under about folder

[10:51:16]  lint finished in 5.90 s 
[10:52:51]  build started ... 
[10:52:51]  template update started ... 
[10:52:51]  template update finished in 5 ms 
[10:52:51]  deeplinks update started ... 
[10:52:53]  deeplinks update finished in 1.59 s 
[10:52:53]  build finished in 1.60 s
```

Currently, I have to re-run `ionic serve` on every change.

How to make this work?

Comment: Could you please add your `package.json`?

Comment: This happens to me aswell when using a sub _components.module.ts_